# Background Image in div disappear after wrapping an <a> tag around it

Tags: html, css

with this code the image inside the div doesn't appear, it appears only if i remove the (a) tag around it. How to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```html
<a href="images/myphoto.jpg">
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(images/myphoto.jpg); background-size: contain;"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: This is not nice coding. It's better if you make this specific `<a>` as `display: block;`, give it the `width` and `height` you want and set the thumbnail you want as a background image to this `<a>`. In that way, you make it behave like a block element. Also, this way, no element will be affecting it and you keep your code short and pointful.

Comment: problems is if i use fixed width for any element it wont be responsive anymore.

Comment: No need to change its position, only its display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

```html
<a href="images/myphoto.jpg">
  <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;height:100%"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: it worked but Div's got small, I cant use fixed widths for it. Am using CSS Grid for responsiveness so the Div's resize automatically.

Comment: check now @Maxim

Comment: It does work when i add height: 100% to the div. Thanks a lot Bhargav

Comment: please edit your answer and remove the body, html portion to mark it as an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If element is empty background won't appear until you set height and width to it.

```css
.thumb{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="images/myphoto.jpg">
  <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300); background-size: contain;"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: just tried, it worked but Div's got small, I cant use fixed widths for it. Am using CSS Grid for responsiveness so the Div's resize automatically.

Comment: element must have content or specific width and height, otherwise background won't be visible.

Comment: is there a way to make the div responsive with using fixed widths?

Comment: I am using Media Queries with CSS Grid system using (fr) fractions, nothing in the site is defined by specific width or height.

Comment: You need to provide relevant code here, if possible add working snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the container has by default height 0px, try to add it

```css
.thumb{
    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="images/myphoto.jpg">
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150); background-size: contain;"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: it worked but Div's got small, I cant use fixed widths for it. Am using CSS Grid for responsiveness so the Div's resize automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to secify a height and width in for the div.
Get the height and width for the  and use it in your css file like this:

```
.thumb {
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
}
```

height and width being the image sizes.

Comment: it worked but Div's got small, I cant use fixed widths for it. Am using CSS Grid for responsiveness so the Div's resize automatically.